# I tried to create tabs using react and redux. It works all fine, but I want the next element to get highlighted when I close the previous element

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

But, I am not able to update the list after deleting the element. NO matter what I change in my reducer, I am not able to update the list that will get reflected in the render method.

My render method :

```
public render() {
    let tablist: any;
    let updatedList = this.props.OpenTabs.slice();

  divStyle = {
      borderBottom: '5px solid white'
    };

    if (updatedList) {
        tablist = updatedList.map((menuitem, index, array) => {
            this.handleColors(menuitem)

            return (

                    <div
                    key={Math.random()}
                    className='tab-elements'
                    style={divStyle}
                    id={menuitem.RoutePath} 
                    onClick={() => this.makeActive(menuitem)}>

                    <Tab
                        MenuText={menuitem.MenuText}
                        IconPath={menuitem.IconPath}
                        RoutePath={menuitem.RoutePath}
                        id={menuitem.id}
                        isActive={menuitem.isActive} />                           
                        <span><label onClick={() => this.crossHandler(menuitem, array[index + 1], array[index - 1])} >X</label></span>                                                 
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
    return <div className='top-nav'>
        <div className='navbar navbar'>
            {/*  <button className= 'testButton' onClick={() => this.handleClose("Documents4Action")}>close frame</button>*/}
            <div className='navbar-header'>
                <Link to="/" onClick={() => { this.handleStateChange(this.props.MainMenuOpen) }}>
                <button className='HomeButton'>
                    <img className='HomeButtonImage' alt='D4ALogo_White' src={String(D4ALogo_White)}></img>
                    </button>
                </Link>  
                <button className='MenuButton' onClick={() => { this.props.togglemenu() }}>
                    <img className='MenuButtonImage' alt='HamburgerIcon_White' src={String(HamburgerIcon_White)}></img>
                </button>
                <div className='tab-position'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        {tablist}
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>;
}
```

Method that handles the operation on clicking the close button:

```
crossHandler(menuitem: any, nextElem: any, prevElem: any) {

    if (menuitem !== undefined && nextElem !== undefined) {
        this.props.history.push(nextElem.RoutePath);
        this.props.removetab(menuitem, nextElem)
    }
    else {
        if (prevElem !== undefined) {
            this.props.history.push(prevElem.RoutePath);
            this.props.removetab(menuitem, prevElem)
        }
        else {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }

    }


}
```

My reducer from redux:

```
  case 'REMOVE_TAB_ACTION':
        const index = state.OpenTabs.map(item => 
        item.MenuText).indexOf(action.MenuItemDetails.MenuText);
        let updatedList = [
            ...state.OpenTabs.slice(0, index),
            ...state.OpenTabs.slice(index + 1),
        ]

        updatedList.map(menu => {
            console.log("checking inside the list")
            if (menu.MenuText === action.MenuItemNextOrPrevDetails.MenuText) {
                menu.isActive = true
            }
            else {
                menu.isActive = false
            }
            console.log(menu)
        });

        return {
            MainMenuOpen: state.MainMenuOpen,
            shoulOverlay: state.shoulOverlay,
            MenuItems: state.MenuItems,
            SelectedMenuItems: state.SelectedMenuItems,
            OpenTabs: updatedList
        }
```

I tried using Object.assign but that did not work either. All my other update methods work great when I use this method, but update after deleting gives me an error. Could anyone please point out where the problem. Any suggestion would be helpful. I cannot use third party libraries, if anyone has any idea of this error please let me know.

Comment: action creator, connect, logs? error=not rendered update?

Comment: There is no error that I can actually see on the console. But the next tab does not get highlighted on closing the previous one.

Comment: logs?  menu.isActive is set?

Comment: menu.isActive is true when I log the array after update. But it does not reflect in my app. Is there a way I can update a specific element after deleting an element from the array in redux. I think the approach I am using for updating after delete action needs to be different.

Comment: check/log it in render - maybe properties are up to date but some elements not re-rendered?

Comment: I can only see the array without the deleted elements. Other than the delete action no other action is performed

Comment: but we're searching for active element ;)

Comment: Yes, there is no element in the array that has 'isActive' as true.

Answer (score 0):

... and we have answer: array.map creates new array with modified elements - checking values inside loop we have only proof that change/conditions were right - not returned array.

```
updatedList = updatedList.map(menu => {
  console.log("checking inside the list")
  if (menu.MenuText === action.MenuItemNextOrPrevDetails.MenuText) {
    menu.isActive = true
  } else {
    menu.isActive = false
  }
  console.log(menu)
});
```

or simpler

```
updatedList = updatedList.map((menu) => {
    menu.isActive = (menu.MenuText === action.MenuItemNextOrPrevDetails.MenuText)
});
```